# how to determine if a location coordinates (LatLng) are a valid driving location, reachable by a car?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I am using google maps version 3 API.
I am using a google map with marker; this marker can be moved freely as the user wishes; however, i want it to generate alert when the user places it on a place not a valid car reachable, which we can drive to.
how can i query for such information from google maps API?

Thanks